# Virtual scroll for Angular 2+

Tags: html, angular, virtualscroll

Hi there!

I am in need to create a table with so many records using Angular 2+. For that, I'm trying virtual scroll. Still, I can't find any documentation or  samples in a working condition.

Please help me for getting started with Angular 2+ virtual scroll.

Comment: Try angular2-infinite-scroll

Comment: No. I can't handle that much records in DOM. If I use the infinite scroll, DOM elements will be increased whenever I scroll down. That's why I'm going for virtual scroll

Comment: https://github.com/rintoj/angular2-virtual-scroll

Comment: I've already tried this. But it is not running.

Comment: Check out this Observable based implementation: https://github.com/dinony/od-virtualscroll

There are also many examples!

Answer (score 1):

You may try [ngx-ui-scroll](https://github.com/dhilt/ngx-ui-scroll). It provides `*uiScroll` structural directive that can be directly used in your App component's template. It currently (v0.0.4) doesn't support table-layout, but if you can use div-layout, it may look like

```
<div class="viewport">
  <div *uiScroll="let item of datasource" class="row">
    <div class="col1">{{item.data1}}</div>
    <div class="col2">{{item.data2}}</div>
    <div class="col3">{{item.data3}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to implement the `Datasource` object in accordance with documentation or code samples from the [demo page](https://dhilt.github.io/ngx-ui-scroll).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend [ngx-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller)

It is very robust handling dozens of thousands of complex elements without trouble. I use it in my open source **Video Hub App** to show a gallery of images & videos (custom elements) allowing the user to change the number of columns. See [GitHub](https://github.com/whyboris/Video-Hub-App) for code.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Angular Material VirtualRepeat https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat

The md-virtual-repeat directive provides a md-on-demand attribute which avoids having an array as the data source provider.

[Edit] The Angular Material VirtualRepeat not being available for angular2 yet, I did a few changes on rintoj/angular2-virtual-scroll to get the data from the backend and not from an array.
it's on github here https://github.com/pnocera/ng2-vscroll

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to achieve the virtual repeat in AngularJs-2. But the above examples are for AngularJs.

Comment: I just realized that, sorry. I have the same thing to do and still couldn't get the angular2-virtual-scroll to work.